# PhP Upload ImageJPEG after orientation correction with iOS image

Tags: php, ios

I've come across some code on this site to help fix the orientation issue in regrades with iOS photos.

Here is the PhP

```
<?php
session_start();


$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
    $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg('/uploads'); // provided that the             image is jpeg. Use relevant function otherwise
    switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
        case 3:
    $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 180, 0);
    break;

    case 6:
    $image = imagerotate($imageResource, -90, 0);
    break;

    case 8:
    $image = imagerotate($imageResource, 90, 0);
    break;

    default:
    $image = $imageResource;
} 
}

imagejpeg($image, $filename, 90);



?>
```

This code seems to work but I havn't seen the outputted image as I can't move the altered image to the server. What I need to do is move the image onto the servers.

I didn't even know that Apple phone did this little bit of extra evil.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this, maybe stripping the EXIF from the image?

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$exif = exif_read_data($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if (!empty($exif['Orientation'])) {
  $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg($filePath); // provided that the             
image is jpeg. Use relevant function otherwise
switch ($exif['Orientation']) {
    case 3:
$image = imagerotate($imageResource, 180, 0);
break;

case 6:
$image = imagerotate($imageResource, -90, 0);
break;

case 8:
$image = imagerotate($imageResource, 90, 0);
break;

default:
$image = $imageResource;
} 
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if its the best practice but if it works!